# Setting of background color of Each row item of listiview in android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

How can we set background color of each row item in a listview when the data is coming dynamically from mysql database using jsonparser and setting the list through simpleAdapter
The vaule is coming in text box and depending on that i have to set the background of each roe in a list of listview.

Comment: You inflate different layouts for different row items based on the values. or you could use a model class with setter and getter and set the color appropriately

Comment: Why inflate different layouts just to change the color? Why not simply set the background color of the list item view?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using SimpleAdapter. You should derive a new class from BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter and then you can customize the color of the views.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this custom adapter in your Listview creation and then you will write your code in this block...

use this code in your activity...

```
  CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
  mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And then here you replace your Layout....

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutSample);;
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

 }
```